# In Haskell how do you extract strings from an XML document?

Tags: xml, haskell

If I have an XML document like this:

```
<root>
  <elem name="Greeting">
    Hello
  </elem>
  <elem name="Name">
    Name
  </elem>
</root>
```

and some Haskell type/data definitions like this:

```
 type Name = String
 type Value = String
 data LocalizedString = LS Name Value
```

and I wanted to write a Haskell function with the following signature:

```
 getLocalizedStrings :: String -> [LocalizedString]
```

where the first parameter was the XML text, and the returned value was:

```
 [LS "Greeting" "Hello", LS "Name" "Name"]
```

how would I do this?

If HaXml is the best tool, how would I use HaXml to achieve the above goal?

Thank!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never actually bothered to figure out how to extract bits out of XML documents using [HaXML](http://www.cs.york.ac.uk/fp/HaXml/); [HXT](http://www.fh-wedel.de/~si/HXmlToolbox/) has met all my needs.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}
import Data.Maybe
import Text.XML.HXT.Arrow

type Name = String
type Value = String
data LocalizedString = LS Name Value

getLocalizedStrings :: String -> Maybe [LocalizedString]
getLocalizedStrings = (.) listToMaybe . runLA $ xread >>> getRoot

atTag :: ArrowXml a => String -> a XmlTree XmlTree
atTag tag = deep $ isElem >>> hasName tag

getRoot :: ArrowXml a => a XmlTree [LocalizedString]
getRoot = atTag "root" >>> listA getElem

getElem :: ArrowXml a => a XmlTree LocalizedString
getElem = atTag "elem" >>> proc x -> do
    name <- getAttrValue "name" -< x
    value <- getChildren >>> getText -< x
    returnA -< LS name value
```

You'd probably like a little more error-checking (i.e. don't just lazily use `atTag` like me; actually verify that `<root>` is root, `<elem>` is direct descendent, etc.) but this works just fine on your example.

---

Now, if you need an introduction to [Arrow](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrow)s, unfortunately I don't know of any good one.  I myself learned it the "thrown into the ocean to learn how to swim" way.

Something that may be helpful to keep in mind is that the `proc`/`-<` syntax is simply sugar for the basic arrow operations (`arr`, `>>>`, etc.), just like `do`/`<-` is simply sugar for the basic monad operations (`return`, `>>=`, etc.).  The following are equivalent:

```
getAttrValue "name" &&& (getChildren >>> getText) >>^ uncurry LS

proc x -> do
    name <- getAttrValue "name" -< x
    value <- getChildren >>> getText -< x
    returnA -< LS name value
```

Comment: There is a HXT tutorial at http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/HXT, but it is relentlessly point-free, so understanding how this relates to the arrow do-notation (as in the example above) is not easy.

Answer (score 3):

Use one of the XML packages.

The most popular are, in order,

1. haxml
2. hxt
3. xml-light
4. hexpat

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, HXT seems like overkill where a simple TagSoup will do :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my **second** attempt (after receiving some good input from others) with TagSoup:

```
module Xml where

import Data.Char
import Text.HTML.TagSoup

type SName = String
type SValue = String

data LocalizedString = LS SName SValue
     deriving Show

getLocalizedStrings :: String -> [LocalizedString]
getLocalizedStrings = create . filterTags . parseTags
  where 
    filterTags :: [Tag] -> [Tag]
    filterTags = filter (\x -> isTagOpenName "elem" x || isTagText x)

    create :: [Tag] -> [LocalizedString]
    create (TagOpen "elem" [("name", name)] : TagText text : rest) = 
      LS name (trimWhiteSpace text) : create rest
    create (_:rest) = create rest
    create [] = []               

trimWhiteSpace :: String -> String
trimWhiteSpace = dropWhile isSpace . reverse . dropWhile isSpace . reverse

main = do
  xml <- readFile "xml.xml"  -- xml.xml contains the xml in the original question.
  putStrLn . show . getLocalizedStrings $ xml
```

The first attempt showcased a naive (and faulty) method for trimming whitespace off of a string.

Comment: TagSoup happily accepts malformed input -- which you might actually like :) -- unfortunately IMO this solution is harder to read.  Minor nit: I'd have expected something more like `trimWhiteSpace = dropWhile isSpace . reverse . dropWhile isSpace . reverse`; yours is more like `removeAllWhiteSpace`.

Comment: Thanks ephemient. I should have had some better sample data. :)

I'll have to make sure that isSpace gets rid of newlines because I had some newlines embedded in my XML.

Comment: Just try for yourself: type `Data.Char.isSpace '\n'` into GHCi.  Yes, newlines are, and have always been, whitespace.  My nit wasn't about that, more along the lines of your `trimWhiteSpace " a b c " == "abc"` which is non-intuitive to me.  Or maybe I'm strange.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I want to keep those internal spaces.  Thanks.